# how to make google map snippet and directly move to google maps from iOS app?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am a beginner in iOS development, i want to build and iOS app that has a map to indicate a restaurant location, but if use Google Map SDK in my iOS app, its size is too big (128 MB). so i think this is not a good option to install Google Map SDK on my apps.

i find an android apps that only shows the snippet of google map location and then if the map is pressed then it will directly move to google maps app in android like this  https://ibb.co/dAYC1b
[image]
[image]

can i have the same process in iOS app?  since google maps apps is not initially installed on iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you should follow the [Google Maps URL Scheme for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme). If Google Maps app is installed it will open; else the Google maps web page will open.

I have not done this but that's how I read it.

If you *really* want to have the Google Maps app you could show a link to the URL for the download - but you can't force it. It is also a pretty annoying user experience and Google will take care of suggesting that the native app be installed, so seeing such a prompt appear twice will be even more annoying.

Comment: Thanks for the clue adam, this is what i need right now as alternative of installing google map SDK on iOS. I also found good article about this https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2015/03/open-google-maps-from-your-ios-app.html but like you said, i also have to compromise with the UX aspect if i implement this